# No route to host, burp

Tags: burp

I'm trying to proxy to any https connection and I have in alert section this message:

> No route host
>   [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO1Zz.png)

[burp certificate add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc4aY.png)

I have tried to solve it, reinstalled burp, reinstalled the certificate, set a manual network configuration.

Does somebody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hey - can you add code samples and please paste the images into the question.Plus add any exceptions/errors your code is giving:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that you can browse these sites directly from your web browser, without Burp.

If you are on a corporate network you may need to use a proxy. In that case you need to set this as an "Upstream proxy" in User options > Connections.

Another possibility is that a host firewall is blocking the outbound connection.

Comment: im not in coporate network and not use firewall, thanks.

Comment: Thanks i got to solve my issue, with your second recomendation